# Output not Displaying as Expected

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, tostring

After struggling for a while but finally overcoming some compiler errors, I was finally able to get my program to compile and run. However, I did not get anywhere near the output I was supposed to get.

The program is supposed to use an Account class and 2 subclasses (SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount) along with several methods to display a type of account history.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Account {
    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;
    private Date dateCreated = new Date();

    public Account() {
      id = 0;
      balance = 0.0;
      annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    } 

    public Account(int id, double balance) {
      this.id = id;
      this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
      return balance;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
      return annualInterestRate;
    }

    public void setId(int newId) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
      this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
      this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
      this.balance = balance * annualInterestRate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
      return dateCreated;
    }

    public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
      return annualInterestRate/12;
    }

    public double withdrawal (double withdrawalAmount) {
      return balance -= withdrawalAmount;
    }

    public double deposit (double depositAmount) {
      return balance += depositAmount;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account savingsAccount = new Account(1122, 20000);
    Account checkingAccount = new Account(1271, 150);
    System.out.println("Accounts Created!");
    System.out.println(savingsAccount);
    System.out.println(checkingAccount);
    savingsAccount.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
    checkingAccount.setAnnualInterestRate(1.25);
    System.out.println("Updating Interest");
    System.out.println(savingsAccount);
    System.out.println(checkingAccount);
    savingsAccount.withdrawal(5000);
    checkingAccount.withdrawal(300);
    System.out.println("Processing Withdrawal");
    System.out.println(savingsAccount);
    System.out.println(checkingAccount);
    savingsAccount.deposit(10000);
    checkingAccount.deposit(500);
    System.out.println("Processing Deposit");
    System.out.println(savingsAccount);
    System.out.println(checkingAccount);
    System.out.println("Thank you for your business!");
    }
  }
```

And here is the output that is displayed when I run this code:

```
Accounts Created!
Account@6aad8bf3
Account@273221e
Updating Interest
Account@6aad8bf3
Account@273221e
Processing Withdrawal
Account@6aad8bf3
Account@273221e
Processing Deposit
Account@6aad8bf3
Account@273221e
Thank you for your business!
```

However, the output is actually supposed to look something like this:

```
Accounts Created!
Savings Account: ID: 1122 Balance: $20000.00 Rate: 4.5%
Checking Account: ID: 1271 Balance: $150.00 Rate: 1.25%
Updating Interest
Savings Account: ID: 1122 Balance: $20900.00 Rate: 4.5%
Checking Account: ID: 1271 Balance: $151.88 Rate: 1.25%
Processing Withdrawals 
Savings Account: ID: 1122 Balance:... Rate: 4.5%
Checking Account: ID: 1271 Balance:... Rate 1.25%
Processing Deposits
Savings Account: ID: 1122 Balance... Rate: 4.5%
Checking Account: ID 1271 Balance... Rate:1.25%
Thank you for your business!
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In addition to not overriding `toString()` you seem to have missed writing a `calculateInterest()` method.

Comment: Think about what the compiler thinks you mean when you call `println()` on your custom class. It can't possibly guess what output you want, so it prints the Class name and a hash code. So that's ugly. But you can change what it prints by overriding the `Object` classes' (remember that all your classes extend `Object` at least) `toString()` method.

Comment: You need to implement a method with the signature `public String toString()` in your class. You don't have any code currently that outputs your account as a String, and Java can't guess how to do that.

Comment: Stupid question, but I'm having trouble finding it. What's the quickest way to format currency to display two decimal points and a $ before the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the below override method to your code :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account [id=" + id + ", balance=" + balance + ", annualInterestRate="
            + annualInterestRate + ", dateCreated=" + dateCreated + "]";
}
```

Solution for your second issue :

Replace Your **setId, setBalance, setAnnualInterestRate** method with below code :

```
public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
      this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
      this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
      this.balance = balance * annualInterestRate;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working better. I've clearly still got a kink in there somewhere though because it's giving me 0.0 for the annualInterestRate and not performing all of the calculations correctly, but it's definitely an improvement.

Comment: Thanks, actually figured that out right before I saw your update. Everything appears to be working now, I just need to do some research on how to multiply by percentages in Java. For example, for my savings account after the interest has been applied to the balance, rather than getting 20,900 like I should be, I'm getting 90000 (it's multiplying the balance of 20000 by 4.5 rather than .045). When I get that corrected I should be good.

Comment: `this.balance = balance * annualInterestRate;`?  Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method in your custom classes to return preferred output

Answer (score 0):

Based partly on [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24987061) ...  you had `toString()` defined in your `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount` classes.  Your problem here is that in your `main` method, you instantiated `Account` instead of `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount`, which means you're not using your subclasses the way the question told you to.

So *don't* override `toString()` again, as recommended in the other answers here.  You've *already done that*.  What you need is to actually use your subclasses.  Change the first two lines of `main` to

```
Account savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(1122, 20000);
Account checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount(1271, 150);
```

and you may also need to add appropriate constructors to `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount`.  If you don't do it this way, then you won't have done what your instructor asked you to.